# Display progress bar on the entire screen for conditional update

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a .aspx page containing few update panels each containing one or two usercontrols. Among these update panels one update panel has usercontrol which shows a PDF and this panel updates on condition.

Issue I am facing is when postback is occurred from any one of the update panel [not the conditional update panel], progress bar doesn't show on the entire screen. Conditional update panel gets highlighted and remaining screen is blurred. 
I want to show progress bar on entire screen regardless any panel causing the postback.
 [Only conditional update panel is highlighted as condition was not met. Progress bar shows below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrMoO.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try to give the progress bar a higher `z-index` using CSS. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works well in chrome. But not in IE.
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/724340/pdf-is-showing-always-on-top-of-all-controls